# Point on the square with a circle inscribed inside it

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I giving a second try to this question. Hopefully, with better problem definition.

I have a circle inscribed inside a square and would like to know the point the radius touches when extended. In the figure A, we have calculated the angle(`θ`), `C`(center) , `D` and `E`. How do i calculate the `(x,y)` of `A` and `B`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the case you've drawn, you already know the $x$ value, assuming the circle has center in $(C_x,C_y)$ and radius $r$, $A_x=B_x=C_x+r.$ As for the $y,$ a little trigonometry helps: $A_y=C_y+r·\tan \theta.$

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coordinates of the center then you add $r$ to the $x$ coordinate and you add $r \tan (\theta)$ to the $y$ coordinate of the center to get coordinates of $A$

Similarly you can find  coordinates of $B$

Answer (score 0):

Describe the circle as 
$$\vec x=\vec m+\begin{pmatrix} r\cos(t)\\ r\sin(t)
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now consider the ray 
$$\vec y=\vec m+\lambda\begin{pmatrix} r\cos(t)\\ r\sin(t)
\end{pmatrix}$$
with $\lambda>0$. 
You want to have the first coordinate for $t\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ of $\vec y$ to be $m_1+r$, hence $\lambda=1/\cos(t)$ and the desired point is
$$\vec m+\frac{1}{\cos(t)}\begin{pmatrix} r\cos(t)\\ r\sin(t)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} m_1+r\\ m_2+r\tan(t)
\end{pmatrix}.$$